# How wait in a loop to execute a task?

Tags: android, loops

```
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
        loadImageFromServer(i);
    }
```

The `loadImageFromServer();` takes sometime to load image from server .

Example:
when `i` is 0, `loadImageFromServer(0)` starts. But then loop executes again before completing the `loadImageFromServer(0)` and starts `loadImageFromServer(1)`. Now I want the loop to wait for that time(I mean, first complete the task of `loadImageFromServer(0)`) and then execute the next loop. How to do that ?

Comment: what you want to do later? You will have to collect the result form all tasks and then deploy at once, where is this code executing?

Comment: The question is very vague. We need more information about how this is being used.

Comment: See the updated question @RScottCarson

Comment: What you want is risky, because it means that if a particular image is not accesible for whatever reason, the execution of the program would be hanged forever, and you don't want that. I suggest you to use a library like Picasso, that will handle for you the loading of the images from URLs.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, ideally you should download multiple images simultaneously, to do that use `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
    int numberOfProcessor = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            numberOfProcessor * 2,
            numberOfProcessor * 2,
            60L,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadImageFromServer();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In case you like to change the implementation using `ThreadPoolExecuter` use the [sample application](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/06/10/downloading-multiple-filesimages-etc-in-android-simultaneously-in-android-using-threadpoolexecutor/)

Comment: I don't know why but this is not working . I want to download images one after one .